# For a Bootstrapper, the FileCheck element isn't finding the file on 64 bit OS in System32

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

Hi I am attempting to create a new boostrapper from my WiX generated MSI.  I have done one and it worked but now I need to do another where I check the file version on the file.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229432%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I should use the FileCheck element.

```
  <InstallChecks>
    <FileCheck Property="VersionDll" FileName="cimwin32.dll" SearchPath="wbem" SpecialFolder="SystemFolder"/>
  </InstallChecks>
```

But it doesn't work for me.

The log generated says:

```
Running check with folder 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem' and file 'cimwin32.dll'
Attempting to find file 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\cimwin32.dll'
Could not find file 'cimwin32.dll' in folder 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem'
Not setting value for property 'VersionDll'
```

Even though the listed path in the log file is correct!  Very confusing.  Any help would be appreciated

I am not sure if this matters or not but I am seeing this on a 64 Windows 7 OS.

**UPDATE**
Based off of help from Micheal and some testing this is a problem with File Redirection on 64 bit machines and the FileCheck tag in the bootstrapper.  Regardless of architecture I need to check Windows/System32/wbem/cimwin32.dll

Comment: This definitely appears to be some problem with 64 bit Operating Systems.  It works fine on 32 bit.

I am not sure what to do since the file I want to check IS in System32 even on a 64 bit OS.  The log says it is looking in the place I want it to...but cannot find it.

Very strange.

Comment: If this is a 32-bit MSI, when it says System32, it means SysWow64.

Comment: Interesting.  Even though there is a "SpecialPath" called "System64Folder"?  I tried putting in an absolute path int SearchPath of "C:\Windows\System32\wbem" and got the same results.  If it is always looking in SysWow64 even when I want it to look in System32 is there a way to make it do look in the literal System32?

Comment: Yup, you mark your package x64 (but then it won't run on a 32-bit system). Or you write a custom action which can work around it through other primitives (likely including a call to Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection). Wait, I think I misread slightly. What I said applies to system searches and such inside an MSI. It may not apply to a bootstrapper (although if it is 32-bit and doesn't intentionally handle 64-bit, the behavior will be similar).

Comment: It can find the file if I drop the dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem (did for testing purposes).  So it is definitely getting confused.

Comment: I checked and I am building 2 MSIs one for 32 bit and one for 64 and setting the package accordingly.  But I don't think that would affect the bootstrapper since it "wraps" around it.  But you may be on the right track Michael.  The bootstrapper is built by my wixproj which only has an 86 platform option.  Seems to me like any Wix/MS Bootstrapper user that uses the FileCheck element will hit this on 64bit.  I'm not sure where to go with this now.

Comment: I did find this http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Installer-related-question-td5992256.html but I can't see the significant difference in GenerateBootstrapper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright.  I got it.  Thanks to Michael Urman for brainstorming with me.  It got me thinking about File Redirection on 64bit OSs that I didn't know happened.

For the bootstrapper to get access to a 32 bit directory on a 64 bit OS it needs to use the alias Sysnative for System32

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So I just created another file check.  One for 32 and one for 64 and I am up and going.

```
<InstallChecks>
    <FileCheck Property="VersionDll" FileName="cimwin32.dll" SearchPath="System32\wbem" SpecialFolder="WindowsFolder" />
    <FileCheck Property="VersionDll64bit" FileName="cimwin32.dll" SearchPath="Sysnative\wbem" SpecialFolder="WindowsFolder" />
</InstallChecks>
```